# How to STOP this time after entering the second activity?

Tags: java, android

I have java code for auto click button to open new activity, but after new activity open this time won't stopped, so Activity 1 is back and run again to auto click button.
I use Code below

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_adsbonus );
    btnN=(Button)findViewById( R.id.btnNext );
    btnR=(Button) findViewById( R.id.btnRe );
    btnR.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent (ActivityAds.this, ActivityStarquiz.class);
            startActivity( i );
        }
    } );
    viewBinds();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btnR.performClick();

        }
    }, 35000);
```

and I try this java code, but not working for kill:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i = new Intent (this, ActivityStarquiz.class);
    i.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    startActivity( i );
    finish();
    finishAffinity();
    System.exit( 0 );
```

Comment: so you want timer to stop if user has clicked the button?

Comment: no... this button auto click to next activity, see btnR.performClick(); any idea?

Comment: this question is very unclear.

Comment: why you are starting `ActivityStarquiz` in backpress? i guess you don't need that

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh
because I think the back press code can overcome this.. but not working

Comment: @DroiDev 
I am studying. if you feel unclear please ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the times this way:

```
//in your activity
Runnable mRunable;
Handler mHandler;

//in on create
mHandler = new Handler();
mRunable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        btnR.performClick();
    }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,35000);

//and when you want to stop
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer... but }; error expected ')' ... how to solved this code?

Comment: hi regev , I try this code but autoclick button not run

Comment: Edited my answer, I put a `;` not in its place. And in your screenshot, you should add a `)` to solve it